# Checking Palindrome numbers in C++

Tags: c++

I'm trying to use  C++ to solve [Project Euler problem 4](http://projecteuler.net/problem=4).

I thought of placing each digit into an array and seeing if the values of the elements are the same in the correct places. This is what I have so far:

```
int digits[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
```

But I can't write the code. How can I take the number and make it seem that way?
I know the basics of C++ (loops and pointers).
How to use adjustable array in C++ and should I use this?
I also don't know what the size of the array should be.
Is there another better algorithm to implement?

Comment: Do you mean a palindrome? I'd read it in as a string.

Comment: Hi John, & welcome to Stack Overflow. What have you tried so far?

Comment: yes. i don't know string commands yet. why you  recommend me to use strings rather than arrays, can i convert int to string and vice verse in c++ like python??

Comment: Since the product of two 3-digit numbers can use at most 6 digits, determining a suitable size of string (or array of decimal digits) is not very hard.

Comment: yes, you can convert `int` to `string` and get string lenght. and string is also array - array of chars.

Comment: @furas, I wouldn't say it *is* an array if you mean `std::string`. It can be used as an array, sure.

Comment: @chris you are right.

Answer (score 0):

If you know array/string length you can loop and compare element [i] with element [length-i-1]

Comment: but the product of the two integers will be int not string

Comment: how i use dynamic array so i dont need to specify the elements?

Comment: @JohnSmith, I guarantee you would find `std::vector` within one minute of looking up "C++ dynamic array".

Comment: you have product of 3-digit number. biggest 3-digit number is 999 so product is 999*999. it is 6-digit number

Answer (score 0):

You can use a loop to check if the ends match:

```
int digits[]={0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0};
int length = sizeof(digits)/sizeof(digits[0]);
for (int i = 0; i < length; i++) {
    if (digit[i] != digits[length - i - 1])
        return false; // at this point, you know the number is not a palindrome 
return true;
```

Comment: what the sizeof(digits) and sizeof(digits[0] equals to? can you give me an example and explain more?

Comment: It is just a way to get the length of an array.

Comment: `sizeof(digits)` gives you size of array (in bytes) - 15 `int` elements gives 60 bytes. `sizeof(digits[0])` give you size of one element in array (in bytes) - size of int (mostly 4 bytes). So 60/4 gives you 15.

Answer (score 0):

Length calculation is a little C-like approach but it does its work.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

bool isPalindrome(int* digit_array, int len) {
    if(len <= 1) return true;
    if(digit_array[0] != digit_array[len-1])
        return false;
    else
        return isPalindrome(++digit_array, len-2);
}

int main() {
    int digits[] = {1, 2, 3, 4};
    int digits2[] = {1, 2, 2, 1};

    // it returns false
    cout << "isPalindrome(digits) => " << isPalindrome(digits, (sizeof(digits)/sizeof(*digits))) << endl;

    // it returns true
    cout << "isPalindrome(digits2) => " << isPalindrome(digits2, (sizeof(digits2)/sizeof(*digits2))) << endl;

    return 0;
}
```

Edit: I just read Project Euler problem 4. Perhaps recursive approach is not the best way to achieve it.

Answer (score 0):

I would convert the integer to a string and check if the reverse of the string is equal to itself.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

int main()
{
    int num = 21334;
    auto s = std::to_string( num );

    if (std::string(s.begin(), s.end()) == std::string(s.rbegin(), s.rend()))
    {
        std::cout << "num is a palindrome";
    } else
    {
        std::cout << "num is not a palindrome";
    }
}
```

Comment: Making string copes is wasteful when you can just test `std::equal(s.begin(), s.begin()+s.length()/2, s.rbegin())`.

Answer (score 0):

I hope you have solved this by now but for those getting stumped recently, there's an easier way to accomplish this without messing with strings.  You can use a combination of the mod function and division (% and /) to look at each digit individually.  The way I solved this is by building the number backwards and then comparing them.  The key here is to know that number%10 will give you the one's place digit and then number/10 will chop of the ones place digit.  Have fun, I really enjoyed working on some PE problems!